# jQuery Smooth Scroll - Scrolling Working Only Once

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, smooth-scrolling

I'm having a problem with jQuery smooth scrolling. I've got a onepager on which I'd like to scroll to different DIVs through anchors. It's not allowed to scroll manually from one DIV to another. To approach this I disable the scrolling on the whole page but set it back to normal for a given period of time while clicking on of my menu buttons.

It works like this: once you've enter the site you see my first DIV with content. When you klick on a link in the menu you see a short animation where an image leave the DIV and than the page scrolls to the next DIV. In the second DIV an image animates in and the text scrolls in. The first time it works but when I'd like to klick on another link the scrolling works but after one second in the right DIV the page jumps back to the top (to the first DIV).

I've already tried to solve this with `event.preventDefault();` and `return false` but nevertheless it jumps to the top.

Can anyone help me please?

```js
     var scrollPosition = [
        self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
        self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
      ];
      var html = jQuery('html, body'); // it would make more sense to apply this to body, but IE7 won't have that
      html.data('scroll-position', scrollPosition);
      html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
      html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
      window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
   
   



$(function() {
  
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function(event) {
   
   event.preventDefault();

   var html = jQuery('html, body');
      var scrollPosition = html.data('scroll-position');
      html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
      window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1])
   
      
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
  
  
  
  setTimeout(function() {
   
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      }, 1500, 'easeInExpo');
   
   
   }, 900);
   
   
   
   setTimeout(function() {
   
 $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
 $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
   
   
   }, 4000);
 
  
   });
  
});
```

```html
<div id="page-one"></div>
<div id="pageone">
  <!-- some content -->
</div> 

<div id="page-two"></div>
<div id="pagetwo">
  <!-- some content -->
</div> 

<div id="page-three"></div>
<div id="pagethree">
  <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

Comment: could you set up a fiddle?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I use WordPress and don't know how to link the images and so on. It's only local.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky without a fiddle but please try the following.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])', function(event) {

   // code here

});
```

I hope this makes sense. The second argument for the .on() function is the selector.